# REST API: Should we validate every route parameter?

Tags: rest

Let's take this route as an example:

```
GET /merchant/{merchant_id}/product/{product_id}
```

By REST API best practices we should validate both: merchant_id and product_id. Most of the times it's irrelevant as validating product_id is usually enough to get the Model.

Is there any practical reason we should validate both: product_id & merchant_id?
Please share your opinions on that.

Comment: Does the merchant id refer to the id of  the product's merchant?

Comment: @AISHWARYAM Yes, these are the products of the merchant. Otherwise there is no point of this structure.

Comment: If that query string is not used anywhere what is the purpose of using it in the URL then?

Comment: This is the question, in fact.

Comment: I guess that both product id and merchant id are used to fetch the product (especially when two or more merchants sell the same product).